# Creating custom top-level menus / toolbars using Monaco editor (eg. File menu)

Tags: monaco-editor

Is it possible to create a custom top level File, Edit, View etc menu using monaco (just like in VSCode). The custom context menu uses the same menus as VSCode (from the looks of it) so it must be buried somewhere in Monaco. Anyone know if I can add my own menu toolbar in Monaco?

Answer (score 0):

Menus outside the editor (application menus, other popup menus etc.) are not implemented in Monaco. You have to create an own document structure with a menu component and embed Monaco there.